# How can I call const member function from destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

Is there any possible way to invoke const member function from destructor, when const object is destroyed?

Consider:

```
struct My_type { 
    ~My_type () { 
        show ();
    }

    void show () { 
        cout << "void show ()" << endl;
    }
    void show () const { 
        cout << "void show () const" << endl;
    }
};
```

And usage:

```
My_type mt;
const My_type cmt;
mt.show ();
cmt.show ();
```

Output:

```
void show ()
void show () const
void show ()
void show ()
```

Can someone explain me why const version of show has not been invoked when **cmt** is destroyed?

Comment: `const_cast<const MyType*>(this)->show();` ? Although, I'm curious about your use case.

Comment: Interesting. Should there be a `~Destructor() const` feature in C++?

Comment: @NeilKirk constant destructor which does not change object?

Comment: @NeilKirk You're destroying the object and its members, how could that possibly be "const"?

Comment: if it is a do nothing destructor sure but otherwise the destructor can't be const

Comment: @Borgleader no he wonder why `this` is not const when called for const object.

Comment: @Borgleader I don't know which one will be used, I want user to decide which one will be invoked by making object const or not const. Your solution will always invoke const version.

Comment: How can a **const** object be modified during its destruction!?!?!?!

Comment: @NeilKirk the same way it is modified during construction

Comment: I fear you need two (interacting) types 'My_type' and 'My_const_type' to achieve your goal.

Comment: @NeilKirk: I recall once wishing there was `const` overloads of constructors and destructors.  I don't recall the use-case, but it had something to do with wanting to storing something as a public member by value in mutable objects, or by const-ref in const objects.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason the non-const overload is being called when on a `const` instance is because cv-qualifiers on the current instance aren't considered during destruction.  [class.dtor]/p2:

> A destructor is used to destroy objects of its class type. The address of a destructor shall not be taken.
>   A destructor can be invoked for a const, volatile or const volatile object. **`const` and `volatile`
>   semantics (7.1.6.1) are not applied on an object under destruction.** They stop being in effect when the
>   destructor for the most derived object (1.8) starts.

You can use a simply bind `*this` to a reference to `const` to get the behavior you need:

```c++
~My_type() { 
    My_type const& ref(*this);
    ref.show();
}
```

Or maybe you can use a wrapper that stores a reference and calls `show()` in its own destructor:

```c++
template<class T>
struct MyTypeWrapper : std::remove_cv_t<T> {
    using Base = std::remove_cv_t<T>;
    using Base::Base;

    T&       get()       { return ref; }
    T const& get() const { return ref; }

    ~MyTypeWrapper() { ref.show(); }
private:
    T& ref = static_cast<T&>(*this);
};
```

Comment: I am afraid the code will not have behavior OP needs. He wants const method called for const object only. I am not sure that is possible.

Comment: Surely can be done with std::is_const<T> and some template trickery.

Comment: @Robinson really? inside ctor or dtor? How?

Comment: The wrapper as above is the cleanest way of doing it.  The one I was thinking of is very clunky.

Comment: As an aside, I think I would prefer to reserve the name `cthis` for a pointer rather than a reference.

Answer (score 3):

Destructor is supposed to do the cleanup of its members/ This, in a sense, destructor is supposed tomodify the contents of the current object whole doing the cleanup. So, destructor has to be non-const. And, a non-const mnember function can call all non-const member function only. This explains.

Comment: Non-const member functions can call const *and* non-const member functions. The behavior being shown in the OP's example is generally unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

I like this question.

Destructors can't be const. They behave like any non-const method. A non-const method calls non-const methods.

But, there are good reasons to call const methods in destructors. (Logging for instance). Having both, a non-const and a const version, called from a non-const method, the non-const is called.

To call the const, it is possible to use static_cast. But... you cannot determine when to cast. (In other words: You don't know if you are const yourself).